# How to catch activation of a specific jQueryUI tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following html:

```
<div id="tabsuseradmin" class="tabui">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1ua">Add Users</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2ua">Delete Users</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1ua">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2ua">
    <div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following inside my js file document ready function:

```
$('.tabui').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/Session/Index/",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    window.location.href = '/Home/Index/'
                }
            }
        });
    }
});


$("#tabs-1ua").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        alert("User add tab has been clicked.");
    }
});
```

Above, you can see I am trying to specify behavior for all tab selections in general using the class `tabui` (this works fine) and also a specific behavior for an individual tab. This specific action does not work (the alert message does not appear and the breakpoint on the alert doesn't get hit). What should I do to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried for *...also a specific behavior for an individual tab*? Can we see the code

Comment: @wmash I just edited my question...didn't copy it over initially.

Comment: @ITWorker your question is still not clear. What 'specific action' are you having problems with. What errors do you see in console? Be specific.

Comment: Is there anything in `#tabs-1ua`? From what I can see, it's just an empty `div`

Comment: @ITWorker are there tabs within `#tabs-1ua`?

Comment: @wmash no there aren't. It is a tab itself.

Comment: @ITWorker then what are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Wouldn't a basic click event suffice?

Comment: @wmash When I click on the tab identified by the div #tab-1ua, I want the alert to appear.

Comment: $("#tabs-1ua") is not the selector to use for tabs() function. Use a click handler. Or put the code in the handler for the tabs container, $('.tabui')

Comment: @Nikki9696 I tried `$("#tabs-1ua").click(function () {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
}); ` and it did not work either

Comment: That's because that's not a valid way to use the click handler  =)  See the posted answers below.

Comment: @ITWorker that is because `#tabs-1ua` never actually gets clicked. It's the anchor that is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you want to do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/eoa9tafm/

```
$(function() {
  $('.tabui').tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
      $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/Session/Index/",
        success: function(result) {
          if (result.length == 0) {
            window.location.href = '/Home/Index/'
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $("a[href='#tabs-1ua']").click(function(event, ui) {
    alert("User add tab has been clicked.");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("a[href='#tabs-1ua']").on('click', function() {
  console.log("User tab clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabsuseradmin" class="tabui">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1ua">Add Users</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2ua">Delete Users</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1ua">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2ua">
    <div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```